# Can we find $x$ and $y$ positive integers such that $f(x,y)$ is a strictely positive integer

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, divisibility, integers

Let us consider the function:

$$f(x,y)=\dfrac{axy+by+cx+d}{rxy+sy+hx+w}$$

Here $f(x,y)$ is the division of two quadratic polynomials with the same degree

where $a,b,c,d,r,,s,h,w$ are non zero integers.

My **question** is:

(1) Given $a,b,c,d,r,,s,h,w$ as integers, can we find $x$ and $y$ rational numbers such that $f(x,y)$ is a **strictely positive integer**.

(2) Given $a,b,c,d,r,,s,h,w$ as integers, can we find $x$ and $y$ **positive integers** such that $f(x,y)$ is a **strictely positive integer**.

**add**

We can assume that $f$ is bijective with respect to $x$ if $y$ is a constant and bijective with respect to $y$ if $x$ is a constant.

Comment: Are there any restrictions whatsoever on $(a,b,c,d,r,s,h,w)$? (For instance, we will obviously have a hard time if $a=b=c=r=s=h=0$, because then our choice for $(x, y)$ doesn't even matter.)

Comment: @Lynn: No. Only they are non zero integers.

Comment: With bijectivity condition, it is easy. Fix some $x$, then choose $y$ such that $f(x, y) =1$ (you can because of surjectivity). Maybe the condition you want is "non constant" instead of "bijective"?

Answer (score 1):

The denominator can be the opposite of the numerator, so that the function is a negative constant. Take for instance $$\frac{xy+x+y+1}{-xy-x-y-1}$$
 in this way $f(x, y) = - 1$ and you have no chance of finding such $(x, y) $!

Let me enounce a simple fact:
*For every fixed integers $u, v$, it exists an integer N of the same sign of $u$ such that for every $n$ of the same sign of $u$ with $|n|>|N|$ we have*

$$un+v >0 $$

As a corollary, we have :
*If u, u' have the same sign, for every v, v' it exists n such that un+v, u'n+v' are positive.*
**Proof**. Take N, N' given by the previous fact: we know they have the same sign. Thus if we take a n of the same sign of N, N', but greater in modulus, we have $un+v, u'n+v'$ both positive.

Now i will show you that if $a, r$ have the same sign, the answer is affirmative in both cases. In fact, choose $x$ of the same sign of $a$, big enough such that both $ax+b, rx+s$ are positive. Then you can find $y$ such that both the linear forms $(ax+b) y + (cx+d), (rx+s) y+(hx+w) $ are positive, because the coefficient of $y$ have the same sign. In conclusion, the quotient

$$\frac{axy+by+cx+d}{rxy+sy+hx+w} $$

Is positive!

Comment: @ Andrea Marino: Can you explain on more detaills.

Comment: I have filled in more details! Is it clearer now?

Comment: @  Andrea Marino: But the last expression is not necessarly  a positive integer.

Comment: hahah, ok, I didn't read that condition. The problem became more interesting! Let me make some changes.

Comment: I have a solution to both the questions I will write in a few days! I have a complete characterization of point (1), while just a counterexample to (2) more refined than the constant function.

Comment: About (2), I have a characterization of 1-variable case which makes me think that the two variable case is reeeeaally complicated. It involves the existence of divisors of some numbers, obtained from the coefficients, that respect some congruence conditions (for instance, "there exist a divisor k of ad-bc s.t. k= d mod c")